# Insert > Rows absent from menu after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, libreoffice

I've newly upgraded to 16.04. The LibreOffice (5.1.4.2) Calc insert menu opens under Unity, but the first item is "Images" - adding rows is apparently impossible. I've tried restarting lightdm and calc - there seems no obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [some UI reorganisation in LO 5.1](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.1#Reorganization_of_the_menus), it isn't specific to ubuntu / unity. The "Insert Rows" entry (as well as inserting / deleting columns and so on) has moved to the new "Sheet" Menu:

[image]

Comment: Goodness me, so it has! Scarcely intuitive, and they haven't updated the built-in help, but it works. Thanks for the solution.